# mysqli_query() generating query error

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to store form data into database using mysqli but it is generating query error my code is given below....
When ever I try to submit the database connection is generating.. the $_POST is working perfectly.. the error only generating by mysqli_query..

```
<?php 
$name = $_POST["firstname"] . " " . $_POST["lastname"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$happen = $_POST["whendidhappen"];
$howlong = $_POST["howlong"];
$howmany = $_POST["howmany"];
$describe = $_POST["describe"];
$whattheydid= $_POST["whattheydid"];
$seenmycat = $_POST["seenmycat"];
$anythingelse = $_POST["anythingelse"];


$dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','abductionreport') 
or die('Database connection error');


$query = "INSERT INTO abductionform (firstname, lastname, email,whendidhappen, howlong, describe, whattheydid, seenmycat,anythingelse)VALUES('$name','$name','$email','$happen','$howlong', '$howmany','$describe','$whattheydid', '$seenmycat','$anythingelse')";



$result = mysqli_query($dbc,$query) or die ("Query Error");

mysqli_close($dbc); 



?>
<h3>Aliens Abducted Me - Report an Abduction</h3>
<p>Thanks for Submiting the form.</p>
<?php 
echo "$name it happend to you on $happen it take $howlong <br>";
echo "Number of aliens: $howmany<br>";
echo "Describe: $describe<br>";
echo "What they did to you: $whattheydid<br>";
echo "Have you seen my cat: $seenmycat<br>";
echo "Anything else : $anythingelse<br>";
echo "Your Email Address is : $email<br>";

?>
```

Comment: `mysqli_error($dbc)` if you want know why you have problems abducting [little bobby](https://xkcd.com/327/).

Comment: here is video of resolved issue:
https://youtu.be/PIwjucN_CHY

Answer (score 0):

`DESCRIBE` is a mysql keyword.  Wrap the column name in backticks.  For that matter wrap your table and all columns in backticks.  Always check that $_POST elements exist with `isset ()` before trying to access them.  Use mysqli prepared statements with placeholders for improved security.  Always perform error checking BEFORE posting to SO.

You also have 9 columns and 10 values in your query  - this will cause a failure every time.

Comment: thanks I have found solution

https://youtu.be/PIwjucN_CHY

Comment: @GhufranKhalil Why are you promoting that video?  It is easier (less vague) to say what fixed it rather than force people to link-chase.  If my answer didn't solve your issue, you don't have to award the green tick, but posting youtube links seems pretty spammy.